# Encode Symfony2 form to JSON

Tags: php, json, forms, symfony, reactjs

I'm running Symfony 2.8, and converting a static site to a ReactJ web-app (making API calls to my Symfony app).

I'd like to get Symfony forms sent over AJAX in JSON, such that I can (re)render them as needed (e.g. when the server adds an error to the form). This also avoids the need to map form field names on ReactJS and Symfony.

Has anyone attempted this, and succeeded? If yes, how?

Comment: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle